# Can't create Prism pages using "prism template pack"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, prism

When creating prism pages in Xamarin Forms app using the prism template pack I get the following error.

> The parameter is incorrect.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG)

I am using VS2015, Prism Template Pack 1.7 and here's my project structure

[image]

Comment: What is your IDE and what version is it? What version of the template pack are you using? What is your project structure (do you have Views and ViewModels folder?)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015, Prism Template Pack 1.7 and yes I do have 'Views' and 'ViewModels' Folders.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was trying to create 'Prism' pages before modifying the app class to inherit from 'PrismApplication'.

I have just noticed that when using the template pack it automatically registers page for navigation within the 'RegisterTypes' method in the App class.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Muhammad's answer above, i also had to change the constructor to the following after inheriting from `PrismApplication`

```
public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer)
{

}
```

And also had to change the `Application` to `PrismApplication` in App.xaml file also.

Comment: Why isn't this a comment instead of an answer?